# A probability sum that I can't seem to solve

Tags: probability, summation

Two friends, Adam and Eve are throwing rocks at a mountain.

Each rock thrown has a probability of hitting the mountain equal $p$

If both of them are throwing rocks at the same time and each thrown rock is independence from the other, what are the chances that Adam hits the mountain $k$ times by the time Eve hits the mountain for the first time?

My idea:

Let $B_n$ be the event that Eve hit the mountain for the first time on the try number $n$

Let $A_n$ be the event that Adam hit the mountain $k$ times in $n$ tries.

$A_n \sim B(n,p)= {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$

$B_n \sim G(p)=(1-p)^{n-1}p$

$P(A_n \cap B_n)=P(A_n)P(B_n) $ (since they're independent)

Now, I am looking to solve this summation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}(1-p)^{n-1}p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n \choose k}p^{k+1}(1-p)^{2n}(1-p)^{-k-1}=\frac{p}{1-p}^{k+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n \choose k}(1-p)^{2n}$$

The problem is I have no idea how to solve the sum, it looks like I can solve it by considering the power series $x^n$ however I need to derivative $k$ times?

$k$ is a number, the series index is $n$.

Comment: did you switch $A_n$ and $B_n$?

Comment: Yes, I accidentally did, I fixed them; thanks!

Comment: First, notice that the sum starts at $n=k$. Next, look at the pmf of the negative binomial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) and recall that a pmf sums up to $1$. Can you use this fact to finish the exercise? How do you prove that the pmf of the negative binomial sums up to $1$?

Comment: @madprob I am trying to see it, the problem is that the index of that series is $k$ while in this series the $k$ is a simple constant that is unrelated to the sum.

Comment: For your purpose, consider that the pmf of the negative binomial is indexed by $n$ and is equal to ${n+k \choose n}(1-p)^{k+1}p^n$.

Comment: The lower limit of your sum should probably be $n = k$, not $1$?

Comment: @BrianTung

It doesn't matter, it's summing $k$ extra zeros since $n \choose k$ is 0 for all $k>n$

Comment: @RabMakh: No, but it's less confusing if we set the lower index to $n = k$, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game can be analyzed more straightforwardly in the following way: Ignore turns in which both Adam and Eve miss the mountain.  Of the cases where at least one of them hits the mountain, Adam wins the turn with probability $\frac{1-p}{2-p}$; Eve wins or ties the turn with probability $\frac{1}{2-p}$.  Adam has to win at least $k$ times before Eve wins or ties, so the probability is just

$$
\left(\frac{1-p}{2-p}\right)^k
$$

If the rules are interpreted such that Adam can hit the mountain for the $k$th time at the same time Eve hits the mountain for the first time and still win the game, then the probability is instead

$$
\left(\frac{1-p}{2-p}\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{2-p}\right)
$$

which is just the same expression, but with the last "Adam wins the turn" term replaced by an "Adam wins or ties the turn" term.

---

I've verified this by simulation (assuming I've properly understood the rules), incidentally.  Feel free to ask about details.

Comment: Very elegant solution, I have a question though. How did you get to $\frac{1-p}{2-p}$ and $\frac{1}{2-p}$ ?

Shouldn't it be $p(1-p)$ (Adam hits and Eve doesn't) and $p(1-p)+pp$ (Eve hits and Adam doesn't or both of them hit)?

Comment: @RabMakh: Yes, but remember those are just the conditional probabilities.  The probabilities I give are conditioned on at least one of them hitting the mountain.  The probability of at least one of them hitting the mountain is $1-(1-p)^2 = 2p-p^2$, so (for instance) $P(\text{Adam hits and Eve doesn't} \mid \text{at least one hits}) = \frac{p-p^2}{2p-p^2} = \frac{1-p}{2-p}$.  Similarly for Eve hitting, conditioned on at least one of them hitting.

Comment: For a concrete example, suppose $p = \frac12$.  Then there are four outcomes, each one with probability $\frac14$.  If we condition on at least one of them hitting the mountain, however (which happens with probability $\frac34$, then the conditional probability of Adam hitting and Eve missing is $\frac13$, and the conditional probability of Eve hitting is $\frac23$.

Comment: You understood the rules properly, well done for the out of the box thinking.

I calculated the series I posted above up to the 100th index for different values of $p$'s and your solution is within $0.04$ error margin, I believe it's correct.

Thank you.